# Compare 2 Pandas Column, over different rows and Output the resultant in a 3rd column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this.

|  | EMPLOYEE_ID | NAME | MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 42 | S | 40 |
| 1 | 40 | G | NaN |
| 2 | T | M | 40 |
| 3 | 0c | H | 42 |

I want a separate column that outputs the Name of the Manager of every person.
So for S manager would be G
for G it would be empty (Non NaN, if possible)
for M it would be G
for H it would be S

Here is my attempt:

```py
name = list(df3[df3["MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_ID"].isin(list(df3["EMPLOYEE_ID"]))]["MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_ID"].unique())
df3.loc[:, "MANAGER NAME"] = False
b_match_idx = df3[df3["MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_ID"].isin(name)].index
df3.at[np.array(b_match_idx),"MANAGER NAME"] = df3["NAME"]
df3
```

But the result is not what I want. Can someone point out the flaw in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do a join with the dataframe on itself by using the `MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_ID` and `EMPLOYEE_ID` columns like this:

```
(
    df3
    .merge(df3[["EMPLOYEE_ID", "NAME"]], how="left", left_on="MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_ID", right_on="EMPLOYEE_ID", suffixes=(None, "_y"))
    .rename({"NAME_y": "MANAGER_NAME"})
    .drop("EMPLOYEE_ID_y", axis=1)
)
```

Which will give the following resulting dataframe:

| EMPLOYEE_ID | NAME | MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_ID | MANAGER_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | S | 40 | G |
| 40 | G | nan | nan |
| T | M | 40 | G |
| 0c | H | 42 | S |

Comment: Thank you for the response, this is giving me an error ```KeyError: 'EMPLOYEE_ID```

Comment: Apologies, used the wrong column name, see the edit.

Comment: I believe this is the correct code? @Oxbowerce
```merged_df3.merge(merged_df3[["EMPLOYEE_ID", "NAME"]], left_on="MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_ID", right_on="EMPLOYEE_ID", how='left').rename({"NAME_y": "MANAGER_NAME"}).drop("EMPLOYEE_ID_y", axis=1)```

Comment: That's indeed correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'EMPLOYEE_ID':['42', '40', 'T', 'Oc'], 'NAME': ['S', 'G', 'M', 'H'], 'MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_ID': ['40', np.NaN, '40', '42']})

def get_mgr_name(x):
    try:
        return df.query('EMPLOYEE_ID == @x')['NAME'].values[0]
    except:
        return np.NaN        


df['Manager_Name'] = df['MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_ID'].apply(lambda x: get_mgr_name(x))
```